# SQL statement ignored in trigger?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I'm getting error in my trigger code

> Errors: TRIGGER UPDATETARGET
>   Line/Col: 2/1 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   Line/Col: 3/9 PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

I'm trying this code on Oracle live SQL:

```
create trigger updatetarget
after insert on src
for each row
     begin
insert into target select * from src
    if
src.id = target.id and src.ename=target.ename and src.comp<>target.comp
update target set (select  src.*, lead(doj) over (partition by ename order by doj)-1,valid = 'N' where doe is not null
else if
src.id = target.id and src.ename=target.ename and src.comp=target.comp
then
DELETE target 
WHERE ID < ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM target t 
WHERE t.ename =target.ename AND t.comp = target.comp 
AND t.id = target.id) 
    end if;
    end;
/
```

Just want to remove this error.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of errors in your code:

- You have to end every statement with a `;`. (All SQL-statements are missing the semicolon)
- The first if-statement has no `then` after the condition.
- What is the part `(select  src.*, lead(doj) over (partition by ename order by doj)-1,` doing? Looks to me as if this is copied there unintenionally.
- `ELSE IF` has to be `ELSIF`.
- The bind variables `src` and `target` will not be understand by the compiler. Are these tables? Then you have to loop over the data using a `FOR` loop or something like that.
- You should not select the data of the table you are triggering on. Better only work with the data of the record inserted (if possible).

So the final statement could look something like the following:

```
create trigger updatetarget
after insert on src
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
for each row
begin
  insert into target (id, ename, COMP, valid)
  VALUES (:NEW.id, :NEW.ename, :NEW.COMP, 'Y'); 

  -- Don't know what the following should do exactly:
  IF src.id = target.id and src.ename=target.ename and src.comp<>target.COMP 
  THEN
    update target 
       set valid = 'N' 
     where doe is not NULL;
  ELSIF src.id = target.id and src.ename=target.ename and src.comp=target.comp
  then
    DELETE target 
     WHERE ID < ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM target t 
                   WHERE t.ename =target.ename AND t.comp = target.comp 
                     AND t.id = target.id); 
  end if;
end;
/
```